# Wifi has stopped working in Ubuntu 14.04 desktop

Tags: wireless, networking, 14.04

Usually wifi connects itself without problems when I boot my PC. Earlier today my PC suddenly re-booted itself, as if there had been a momentary power-cut, but I did not notice my lights flicker, and my radio-alarm clock did not re-set itself. Since then I have not been able to connect to wifi, so I wonder if something got corrupted.

My Ubuntu laptop and Android tablet both connect via wifi, and I can connect the PC fine with an ethernet cable; so the problem is not my router.

I've tried following various online toubleshooting guides without success. Can any kind soul lead me through the diagnostic process to find the problem?

lshw produces this:

```
  *-network
   description: Wireless interface
   physical id: 1
   bus info: usb@2:1.5
   logical name: wlan0
   serial: 00:0d:81:a2:5e:8f
   capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=r8712u multicast=yes wireless=unassociated
```

iwconfig gives this:

```
  wlan0     unassociated  Nickname:"rtl_wifi"
      Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Sensitivity:0/0  
      Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off
      Link Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
lo        no wireless extensions.
eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

lsusb includes this line:

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bda:8172 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8191SU 802.11n WLAN Adapter
```

Let me know what other info you need. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[UPDATE:]
Well, this is bizarre. I continued using the PC with a wired connection until the end of the day. This morning it connected (at the 2nd attempt) to wifi. Running lshw again, I find this -- presumably crucial -- difference:

```
wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
```

and with iwconfig:

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"VM547009-2G"  Nickname:"rtl_wifi"
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: C4:04:15:F2:81:E0   
      Bit Rate:72 Mb/s   Sensitivity:0/0  
      Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off
      Link Quality=98/100  Signal level=100/100  Noise level=0/100
```

So, although my immediate problem seems to have resolved itself, I would be grateful to anyone who can tell me what happened / what I did wrong / how I can avoid this happening again in future!